# Ruby on rails submit button doesn't call the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, submit, call

I am new to ruby on rails,
I want to make a simple Text Field where you can change the content and store it in the database. But the submit button doesn't call the Profiles controller. "Foo" is never raised.

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   devise_for :users
   get 'welcome/user'
   resources :profiles
end
```

user.html.erb:

```
...
<%@profile=Profile.find_by user_id: current_user.id%>
<%= form_for (@profile) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name%>
<%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

profiles_controller.rb:

```
class ProfilesController < ActionController::Base
  def update
     raise "foo"
  end
end
```

Comment: Look at your server to see what action is called

Comment: `<%@profile=Profile.find_by user_id: current_user.id%>` - that stuff definitely belongs to controller.

Comment: Probably, you need to provide action to `form_for` helper.

Comment: If I change it to this `<%= form_for (@profile) , :url => url_for(:action => "update", :controller => "profiles", :profile_id => @profile.id) do |f| %> `then No route matches `{:action=>"update", :controller=>"profiles", :profile_id=>3}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really separate this out.

```
class ProfilesController < ActionController::Base
  def edit
    @profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
  end

  def update
    raise "Foo"
  end
end
```

And create the relevant view file, edit.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for (@profile, method: ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

As for the issue itself, I would suggest maybe looking at the log files. On your terminal run `tail -f /path/to/app/log/*` and then try and submit the form. It would be unusual that you don't see anything here, if that is the case, use your browser's developer tools to inspect the form. You should have something like:

```
<form id="profile-form" action="/profiles/1" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Look out for `action="/profiles/1` where 1 is the ID of the Profile entity.

Comment: Thanks, the "foo"-message is actually raised, I expected to see it in the browser.